# Display Related products for a specific product attribute value in single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In WooCommerce, I have set a `COLLECTION_ID` product attribute for my products.

I would like to display all related products to this `COLLECTION_ID` product attribute value on single product pages. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add your own settings in the "Settings section" inside the function. For the defined product attribute name, this function will take the first corresponding term set for the current product *(as an attribute can have many terms in a product)* and will display all similar products just before "Upsells products" and "Related products".

The code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_output_product_collection', 12 );
function custom_output_product_collection(){

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS --- ##

    $attribute = "Color"; // <== HERE define your attribute name
    $limit     = "3";     // <== Number of products to be displayed
    $cols      = "3";     // <== Number of columns
    $orderby   = "rand";  // <== Order by argument (random order here)

    ## --- THE CODE --- ##

    global $post, $wpdb;

    // Formatting the attribute
    $attribute = sanitize_title( $attribute );
    $taxonomy  = 'pa_' . $attribute;

    // Get the WP_Term object for the current product and the defined product attribute
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    $term = reset($terms);

    // Get all product IDs that have  the same product attribute value (except current product ID)
    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE '$taxonomy' AND t.term_id = '{$term->term_id}' AND tr.object_id != '{$post->ID}'" );

    // Convert array values to a coma separated string
    $ids = implode( ',', $product_ids );

    ## --- THE OUTPUT --- ##

    echo '<section class="'.$attribute.' '.$attribute.'-'.$term->slug.' products">
        <h2>'.__( "Collection", "woocommerce" ).': '.$term->name.'</h2>';

    echo do_shortcode("[products ids='$ids' columns='$cols' limit='$limit' orderby='$orderby']");

    echo '</section>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: This is a great code snippet Loic. Would it be possible to modify the code so only products of the same color **within the same product category** are fetched?