# Woocommerce Related products by attribute, product link is missing from image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using *"[Display Related products for a specific product attribute value in single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960219/display-related-products-for-a-specific-product-attribute-value-in-single-produc/49961446#49961446)"* answer code that works to show related products by a single attribute in Woocommerce.

I am using this settings:

```
$attribute = "family"; // <== HERE define your attribute name
$limit     = "60";     // <== Number of products to be displayed
$cols      = "6";     // <== Number of columns
$orderby   = "rand";  // <== Order by argument (random order here)
```

The problem it is only linking the title and not the product image. I have users trying to click the product image who get frustrated that it does not take them anywhere. They do not realize they need to click the title. could someone please help me link the image and the title with the product url.

Here is a link to a product so you see what I mean
http://www.2ndave.info/2ndavewp/product/10-25w-cilindro-novartis-wall-sconce-131034/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you are using the code from an existing StackOverFlow answer, you should first always add the link in your question. As you are not making real changes in the code, just a link is enough explaining what are your settings.... Now sorry but the code **works perfectly** on last woocommerce version... **so you are making something wrong somewhere.**

Comment: When looking at your website provided link, **the problem is related to your theme customizations** as on a normal theme (not customized) like storefront or most others, it works perfectly. My code is using a WoCommerce shortcode that includes the product link all over each product (including image)…