# Show related products within same product category and color

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried [Display Related products for a specific product attribute value in single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960219/display-related-products-for-a-specific-product-attribute-value-in-single-produc/49961446#49961446) code snippet and it returns me the following section under my product details:

[image: Products having same color]

However, as you can see I'm also getting an accessory (the last item is a bag) with this color between the shoes, so what I'd like to have is the products:

- having the same color
- having the same product category

How can I modify this code to reach this?

### My attempt

I'll probably need to add this somewhere to fetch the current category of the product:

```
$category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

Now, I'll also have to modify the query to take into account the product category.

I got the results I desire with the following nested query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id

FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id

WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE 'pa_kleur' AND t.term_id = '286'
AND tr.object_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
    JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.term_id = '305'
)
```

Now, I still have to fill the color ID & category ID dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Below my solution which you can insert in functions.php:

```
/* OTHER PRODUCTS OF THE SAME PRODUCT CATOGORY IN THIS COLOR */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_output_product_collection', 12 );

function custom_output_product_collection(){

## --- YOUR SETTINGS --- ##

$attribute = "kleur"; // <== HERE define your attribute name
$limit     = "4";     // <== Number of products to be displayed
$cols      = "4";     // <== Number of columns
$orderby   = "rand";  // <== Order by argument (random order here)

## --- THE CODE --- ##

global $post, $wpdb;

// Formatting the attribute
$attribute = sanitize_title( $attribute );
$taxonomy  = 'pa_' . $attribute;

// Get the WP_Term object for the current product and the defined product attribute
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
$term = reset($terms);

// Set the product category
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
$category = reset($categories);

// Get all product IDs that have the same product attribute value (except current product ID) & same product category
$product_ids = $wpdb->get_col
( "        
SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE '$taxonomy' AND t.term_id = '{$term->term_id}' AND tr.object_id != '{$post->ID}
AND tr.object_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tr.object_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
    JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.term_id = '{$category->term_id}'
)
" );

// Convert array values to a coma separated string
$ids = implode( ',', $product_ids );

## --- THE OUTPUT --- ##

echo '<section class="'.$attribute.' '.$attribute.'-'.$term->slug.' related products">
    <h2>'.__( "Andere producten in dit kleur", "woocommerce" ).': '.$term->name.'</h2>';

echo do_shortcode("[products ids='$ids' columns='$cols' limit='$limit' orderby='$orderby']");

echo '</section>';
}
```

Tested on my website & works:
[image: Only beige products of same product category shown]

Comment: Only problem with this snippet is: if you have only 1 product in this product category with that particular color, the products returned are random as the query returns an empty result probably. If anybody knows how to resolve this, please tell me! Thanks!